# I ___ there until I was 12

Tags: tense

I saw the following tense question the other day:

> I _____ there until I was 12.

Verb to be used was "live", and it was a negation.

The student answered "wasn't living", it got marked as wrong and corrected to "didn't live".

I feel that "didn't live" is indeed more correct, but I don't think that "wasn't living" is wrong. I could have easily used it in spoken and maybe even written language.

Could somebody please explain the correctness or not of the two types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "didn't live" and "wasn't living" are grammatically correct, as are several other past tense forms  (hadn't lived, hadn't been living, wouldn't have lived are all "correct")

It is most natural to use "didn't live". The verb "live" (in the sense of "reside") is used in simple tense forms to give a permanent address.

> I live in America, and expect to remain here indefinitely.

Whereas the continuous form is for temporary addresses.

> I'm living at my aunt's house, until I can save up for a deposit on a flat.

The given sentence doesn't provide much context, so you'd assume that the speaker is talking about her permanent address, and so "didn't live" is the most natural answer.

Comment: 'wouldn't have lived'? Is it a natural use, since it sounds very odd to me?

Comment: It would be very rare but it is grammatically correct.  It is a conditional. It could be used, for example, if someone is unsure of when they starting living somewhere:  "I wouldn't have lived there until I was 12, because that is the age that my dad left my mum.  Before that we moved around a lot.  I know I was living there when I was 15 because I remember by 15th birthday party in the back garden".

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: When I was teaching English, I would often give marks for 'correct but less usual/natural, maybe requiring some context' answers. You that say 'wasn't living' was marked wrong and corrected to 'didn't live'. Who did that?